# How to add a import file with JS and CSS on a Spring MVC 4 and HTML5 application?

Tags: javascript, css, html, spring

In my Spring MVC 4 application, I have `WEB-INF/html/include/imports.html` file that has all the JavaScript and CSS, I should need throughout the application.

The author of [this HTML Imports article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) suggests the use of a link tag on my HTML5 pages, like:

```
<link rel="import" href="include/imports.html" />
```

Where, on each page I use this tag, I'd need to adjust the relative path. So far, no news. I'm used to doing it on JSP.

So, I have this very simple login page, mapped on my controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    return "login";
}
```

But whenever I try to load this login page, I get a console output of:

```
Apr 06, 2016 8:19:30 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hrm/include/imports.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

On Chrome's Developer Tools, I get this, saying it failed load the resource.

[image]

The WEB-INF structure is:

[image]

I don't really need this particular file mapped on my any controller, but I need it to be loaded by my pages.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the path to your html file correct? /htm/include/imports.html? It looks like the '/htm' may be where you are off.

Comment: @EricBellDesigns, the path is correct. I edited the question, providing further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the file `imports.html` where your static resources are, in that case you don't need a dedicated mapping in a `Controller`, and the browser will be able to download it.